# Avoiding CSS classes on each html table cells?

Tags: html, css, cell, centering

I have a HTML table where some column cells' text must be left-aligned and centered for other columns. How can I avoid setting CSS classes on each cell? Can one simplify it?

I have created an example on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dgns4/).

Here is the HTML:

```
<table id="myTbl">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="Col-1">
        <col class="Col-2">
        <col class="Col-3">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class="makeItLeft">&nbsp</td><td class="makeItCenter">AAA</td><td class="makeItCenter">BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="makeItLeft">DDD</td><td class="makeItCenter">4</td><td class="makeItCenter">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="makeItLeft">EEE</td><td class="makeItCenter">2</td><td class="makeItCenter">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="makeItLeft">FFF</td><td class="makeItCenter">2</td><td class="makeItCenter">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="makeItLeft">GGG</td><td class="makeItCenter">&#x2713;</td><td class="makeItCenter">88</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#myTbl {
    width: 96%;
    background-color: green;
}

#myTbl td {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.Col-1 {
    background-color: red;
}

.Col-2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.Col-3 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.makeItCenter {
    text-align: center;
}

.makeItLeft {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add those line on your Css

```
#myTbl tr td:nth-child(2),#myTbl tr td:nth-child(3){
    text-align:center;
}
#myTbl tr td:nth-child(1){
    text-align:left;
}
```

and remove your below code along with the td classes

```
.makeItCenter {
text-align: center;
}

.makeItLeft {
 text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a general rule to set alignment to center, and then override the first column with a left alignment:

```
#myTbl td {
    text-align: center;
}

#myTbl td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: I have just noticed it only works with #myTbl td:first-child and not #myTbl tr:first-child, but...

Comment: This is the simplest and least computationally expensive method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the power of [CSS Pseudo-Class Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child):

```
#myTbl td {
    text-align: center;
}

#myTbl tr td:nth-child(1) {
    text-align: left;
}
```

CSS Pseudo-Class selectors allow you to choose various things like first-of-type, first-child, nth-child, last-child, only-of-type, and more, for these sticky situations. The above code will set the rule of centering the content of all the `td`s, which are all children of `tr`s. Then, for each first `td` child of each `tr`, it will override the centering with a left-align rule.